# "Override" Configuration Table for WHERE clause

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have a table which logs alarms from one of our applications, like below, and we report on these.  Sometimes, however, there may be an alarm or set of alarms that we want to ignore due to some reason or another, e.g., running a test, or someone forgot to turn alarming off for that time period.

I want to create a configuration table which will have, say, a ChartId, a StartTime, and an EndTime, and an Active bit (i.e., use this rule or don't).

The below script works, for the most part, except if I have multiple rows in the @ReportAlarmOverride table for a given ChartId... say we want to ignore alarms from 2:00pm - 3:00pm for ChartId = 1 and then again from 4:00pm - 5:00pm.

```
DECLARE @ReportAlarmOverride TABLE
(
ReportAlarmOverrideId INT IDENTITY(1,1),
ChartId INT,
Active BIT,
StartTime DATETIME,
EndTime DATETIME,
LastModifiedTime DATETIME DEFAULT GETDATE()
)
INSERT INTO @ReportAlarmOverride
SELECT 1, 1, GETDATE() - 1, NULL, NULL UNION
SELECT 3, 1, GETDATE() - 1, GETDATE(), NULL UNION
SELECT 5, 1, GETDATE() - 3, NULL, NULL UNION
SELECT 7, 1, GETDATE() - 1, NULL, GETDATE() --UNION 
--SELECT 3, 1, '2012-11-12 16:09:20', '2012-11-12 16:09:21', NULL --Adding this row makes SELECT below stop working

SELECT  Alarm.AlarmTime, AlarmOverride.StartTime, AlarmOverride.EndTime, *
FROM dbo.AlarmLogSummary Alarm
JOIN dbo.AlarmConfiguration AlarmConfig ON Alarm.AlarmConfigurationId = AlarmConfig.AlarmConfigurationId
LEFT JOIN @ReportAlarmOverride AlarmOverride ON AlarmConfig.ChartId = AlarmOverride.ChartId
WHERE Alarm.AlarmTime > GETDATE() - 2
AND ((AlarmOverride.Active = 1 AND Alarm.AlarmTime NOT BETWEEN AlarmOverride.StartTime AND ISNULL(AlarmOverride.EndTime, GETDATE()))
OR Active = 0)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of joining the @ReportAlarmOverride table, try putting this logic in the WHERE clause as follows:

```
DECLARE @ReportAlarmOverride TABLE
(
ReportAlarmOverrideId INT IDENTITY(1,1),
ChartId INT,
Active BIT,
StartTime DATETIME,
EndTime DATETIME,
LastModifiedTime DATETIME DEFAULT GETDATE()
)
INSERT INTO @ReportAlarmOverride
SELECT 1, 1, GETDATE() - 1, NULL, NULL UNION
SELECT 3, 1, GETDATE() - 1, GETDATE(), NULL UNION
SELECT 5, 1, GETDATE() - 3, NULL, NULL UNION
SELECT 7, 1, GETDATE() - 1, NULL, GETDATE() --UNION 
--SELECT 3, 1, '2012-11-12 16:09:20', '2012-11-12 16:09:21', NULL --Adding this row makes SELECT below stop working

SELECT  Alarm.AlarmTime, *
FROM dbo.AlarmLogSummary Alarm
    JOIN dbo.AlarmConfiguration AlarmConfig ON Alarm.AlarmConfigurationId = AlarmConfig.AlarmConfigurationId
WHERE Alarm.AlarmTime > GETDATE() - 2
  AND NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM @ReportAlarmOverride Override
                    WHERE Override.ChartId = AlarmConfig.ChartId
                      AND Override.Active = 1
                      AND Alarm.AlarmTime BETWEEN Override.StartTime AND ISNULL(Override.EndTime, GETDATE())
```

The only problem is that you won't be able to return the override data in the query. I hope it is not needed.